# PHP/AJAX: Is it sleep() that blocks all requests to the same script?

Tags: php, ajax, sleep

I have a PHP script which, when called, does some stuff, then sleeps for 3 seconds, then echoes its result.

And then I have this page which calls the script above (with an Ajax request) every `1/10` of second. When I get the response, I write a number inside a div element.

The problem is, the onreadystatechange handler is fired every 3 seconds, and writes 30 numbers all together.
Are there any other alternatives to `sleep()` that behave like I need?

Here is the code snippet of the page that gets requested:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
$time=microtime(true)*10000;
changemystatus(1, $time); //this writes to a database
sleep(3);
if ($time>=getmytime()){ //getmytime() reads the data previously written by changemystatus()
    setstatus(0); // still writing to that DB
    echo("1");
}else echo ("0");
```

Basically I want the "status" field in the DB to be changed to 0 if the user is not sending requests anymore (because he's gone, or his connection went down, or he has disabled JS or whatever) so that other players may know he's now "offline".

Comment: The server should be Apache.

Comment: Are you trying to get the progress of a PHP script?  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: The question is not precise enough, you will have to specify more details. Please post the code.

Comment: Because after I've slept for the 3 seconds I check if the scrpit has been called again meanwhile: if it has not, the user has disconnected. (I also added ignore_user_abort(true) )

Comment: So your goal is to see if a user was waiting for a PHP script to finish?  What is your final goal?

Comment: No, I want to make sure that the user is active and connected to that page.
It is part of a turn-based browsergame

Comment: Are you using the session? I've seen some Apache configurations that, where they use the session, block such that a script may be run only by one user at one time. Perhaps add your Apache config (MPM, FastCGI, accelerator) to your question.

Comment: It is not "mine", it's on a webhosting platform. I can't alter it, I'll see if I can at least read it but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer: if you want to detect if users are still active record the timestamp of their last communication with the server.

Then define some cutoff point, say: 5 minutes.

```
if ($last_active < (time() - 5 * 60)) {
    // user is inactive
}
```

Comment: Something has to call it. And it can't be JS, since I can disable it and then exit the bage and make it look like I'm still online.

Comment: The _server_ keeps the `$last_active` timestamp. If the client does nothing (ie. sends no requests) `$last_active` will eventually dip under _5 minutes ago_ and there's your inactive detection.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I meant. I mean, this code snippet has to be called at a certain point, somewhere, by someone. Where? In simple words, where do I copy-paste this?

Comment: Where you would check `$status === 0` otherwise.

Comment: Well, I would use a query, "WHERE status = 1". I see... It could work. Still, I'd like to figure out what the hell is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can *'sleep'* in JavaScript with `setTimeout`.

Ex:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("3 seconds have passed");
}, 3000);
```

This doesn't block JavaScript or the browser because `setTimeout` is asynchronous. It will schedule an event to fire after 3 seconds (3000 miliseconds) which executes the function.

Comment: But the user can alter it with things like greasemonkey, can't he?

Comment: The user can spam your service if he wants, calling it 100 times in one second. The `sleep` is going to do nothing to prevent that kind of abuse. If you do want to prevent abuse you'll need to do something a lot more involved.

Comment: Well, that's okay, I want it to be called as many times as possible in one second.